# What is the difference between probability distribution and probability simplex?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was watching a [Reinforcement Learning theory course](https://nanjiang.cs.illinois.edu/cs598/) presented by Nan Jiang, and I noticed that he's using probability simplex instead of a probability distribution. So, I wonder what is the difference between probability distribution and probability simplex.

Comment: The probability simplex is a simplex whose points are probability distributions.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex, a probability simplex is defined as
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^k \ : \ \sum_{i=1}^k x_i = 1, x_i \geq 0 \ \forall i\}$$
or in other words, a finite set of non-negative real numbers that sum to 1 (also called a convex combination).

For any probability space, you can partition your sigma field (set of observable events) into a probability simplex, which could be useful for optimization.